# Conexão entre o oracle db e java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle, eclipse

Não estou conseguindo conectar o Oracle data base com o Java, print a seguir : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQK33.jpg

Já tentei utilizar outra versão do jar ojdbc (8 e 11) e mesmo assim aparenta não reconhecer a biblioteca de jeito nenhum!

Ja fiz todo o processo de adicionar o JAR, Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARs...

Comment: Você [já postou esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/590263/70). Se tiver algo a complementar, pode [editar aquela postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/590263/edit), que ela automaticamente é destacada para uma revisão da comunidade. Para evitar descentralização de informações o campo de comentários foi desativado nesta postagem, mas está funcional na postagem original.